# Rails better solution for joins query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, join, activerecord

Is there better solution for this query?

```
Video.where.not(id: Video.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: [20,21,22]}).select(:id))
```

For me it seems that this is such overkill query, but I don't know how to write better solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something I'm missing about what you want your query to do, why not just use the inner query? or are you running into cases where videos don't always have a category?

inner query:

```
Video.joins(:categories).where.not(categories: { id: [20,21,22]})
```

If videos don't always have category:

```
Video.includes(:categories).where.not(categories: { id: [20,21,22]})
```

Comment: I want to get all videos which doesn't have these categories.

I don't know why but the query I posted works, but yours doesn't.

Comment: Try using eager_load instead of joins/includes or write left outer join query in joins call. When we use joins or includes it does inner join with the other table. If you need all videos except  the one associated with category [20,21,22] you need to take left outer join with condition.